# Parametrization of a paraboloid part

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

Find the parametric equation of the surface $S$, where $S$ is the part of the paraboloid $z=x^2 + y^2 + 1$ bounded by the plane $z=2x+3$

**My attempt**

The OXY projection of $S$ is $x^2 + y^2 + 1 = 2x + 3$. Then, it is the disk 
$$(x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 3$$ Then, the first two components of a parametrization of $S$ would be
\begin{align*}
x(r,\theta) &= r\cos\theta + 1\\
y(r, \theta)&= r\sin\theta
\end{align*}

The answer gives $z(r, \theta) = r^2 + 1$. But why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If $x(r,\theta) = r \cos \theta$ and $y(r, \theta) = r \sin \theta$, then $$z(r, \theta) = x^2 + y^2 + 1 = (r \cos \theta)^2 + (r \sin \theta)^2 + 1 = r^2 + 1.$$  However, the limits of $r$ under this parametrization will depend on $\theta$ in a nontrivial way.  To rectify this, note that the projection of the boundary in the $xy$-plane is the circle $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 3$, hence we may write $$(r \cos \theta - 1)^2 + (r \sin \theta)^2 = 3,$$ and solving for $r$ yields its dependence on $\theta$:  $$0 \le r \le \sqrt{\frac{5+\cos 2\theta}{2}} + \cos \theta.$$  Consequently, we can formulate a parametrization as follows:  $$\begin{align*} x &= r \Bigl(\sqrt{\tfrac{1}{2}(5+\cos 2\theta)} + \cos \theta\Bigr)\cos \theta, \\ y &= r \Bigl(\sqrt{\tfrac{1}{2}(5+\cos 2\theta)} + \cos \theta\Bigr)\sin \theta, \\ z &= \biggl(r \Bigl(\sqrt{\tfrac{1}{2}(5+\cos 2\theta)} + \cos \theta\Bigr)\biggr)^{\!2} + 1,\end{align*} \qquad r \in [0,1], \; \theta \in [0,2\pi).$$

[image]

This removes the dependency of the radius parameter $r$ on the angle $\theta$ by rescaling it according to how "far out" you need to go from the origin at a particular angle.  You can see this effect in the picture: the curves of constant $r$-values are more widely spaced in the region of the surface that is farther from the origin.  It isn't *necessary*, but it does make the parametrization "nice" in the sense that the range of the parameters do not depend on each other.